# What is #<..> on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I picked a row of Model by

> `@name = Quest.where(category: 'cat1').sample(1)`

and print on view like this

? `<p><%= @name %></p>`

then `[#<Quest id: 4, name: "q4", category: "cat1", content: "d", description: "d", created_at: "2017-07-21 08:28:00", updated_at: "2017-07-21 08:28:00">]` printed out on view

what is it?? and

what is mean of `#<..>`??

Comment: It represents an object of Quest model.

Comment: I want to use only "id". Can you say me how to do ??

Comment: use `<p><%= @name.id %></p>`

Comment: Then, it makes "NoMethodError by undefined method `id` "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@name` represents an array of single object of Quest model. To get the id of that object, use

```
 <p><%= @name.first.id %></p>
```

or change your controller code to

```
@name = Quest.where(category: 'cat1').sample
```

and then do

```
<p><%= @name.id %></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sample` instead of `sample(1)` as the first one will return you one instance instead of an array with one element

```
@question = Quest.where(category: 'cat1').sample(1)
#=> [#<Quest id: 4, name: "q4", category: "cat1", content: "d", description: "d", created_at: "2017-07-21 08:28:00", updated_at: "2017-07-21 08:28:00">]
```

This above statement will return you an array with 1 element. So, instead use

```
@question = Quest.where(category: 'cat1').sample
#=> #<Quest id: 4, name: "q4", category: "cat1", content: "d", description: "d", created_at: "2017-07-21 08:28:00", updated_at: "2017-07-21 08:28:00">
```

and then you can access the `Question` attributes

```
<p><%= @question.name %></p>
```